# How to multiple endpoint with multiple backendpool in azure frontdoors

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

In my application, I have 4 AppServices (2 web app and 2 API in East US), Now I want deploy all 4 AppServices in a different region (West US) to provide high availability.

I planning to using Azure frontdoors as a load balancer and it's working fine for 1 AppService.

**Problem-** I have created 4 backend pools, how to create 4 different frontends? Do I need to setup custom domain first? Or Do I need to create 4 different azure frontdoors for each type of AppService?

I am using ARM templates to setup my resources.

Hight Level Architecture of my application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do a number of things:

- Create four different custom (sub-)domains and add them as frontends. Then assign a routing rule for each frontend to its corresponding backend pool (rule `/*`)
- Create four different routing rules based on the path (`/app1/*` routes to BE-pool 1, `/app2/*` to BE-pool 2, etc.). This way all can use the same frontend domain.
- If you don't want to do either of those, create four different front doors and each gets only one backend pool (I really wouldn't do that)

Comment: If I will go with point no 2, My application URL will change right? like abc.com/site1 abc.com/site2

Comment: yes, exactly. but interally could rewrite (in FrontDoor) so that abc.com/site1 will actually forward to mysite1.azurewebsites.net/ (on the root)

Comment: It might create another problem in SEO and other areas where URL change need to update